# Autobahn python twisted wamp client examples give TypeError for _parseClientTCP()

Tags: python, autobahn, twisted.internet, wamp-protocol

I wanted to run the Autobahn Python twisted examples listed here https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/twisted/wamp/basic.  However, running the client.py always give me TypeError:

```
$ python client.py -c pubsub.basic.frontend.Component
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 88, in <module>
    client = clientFromString(reactor, args.websocket)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/endpoints.py", line 1029, in clientFromString
    kwargs = _clientParsers[name](*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: _parseClientTCP() takes exactly 0 arguments (2 given)
```

Environment details: Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS 64-bit, Python 2.7.3, Autobahn 0.8.6

Installation steps:

```
aptitude install python-twisted python-dev
aptitude install python-pip
pip install --upgrade twisted
pip install autobahn
pip install --upgrade autobahn
```

Please help! How can I get the examples to run?  server.py runs fine.

Comment: What Twisted version? Can you run: `python -c "import twisted; print(twisted.__version__)"`? What does that give?

Comment: And try: https://gist.github.com/oberstet/9781098

Comment: It is 11.1.0. Is this the compatible version for Python 2.7?

Comment: This is too old for Twisted client endpoint support. So not, please upgrade your Twisted. The current version is 13.2

Comment: In general, I'd recommend not going with a distro package of Python or Twisted. Distro packages are unneeded, often outdated and sometimes broken.

Comment: I am wary of breaking the compatibility, thus I hesitate to download and install things on my own.  I would greatly appreciate if you could show me how to install the latest packages on Ubuntu without using the distro packages.

Comment: Somehow, after doing sudo aptitude update, my twisted version is now the latest.

Comment: If I use your command, I see 13.2.0. However, I still get the same TypeError.  Another command gives me 11.1.0 still: `>>> import twisted
>>> twisted.version
Version('twisted', 11, 1, 0)
`

Comment: It's hard to say whats going on your system. FWIW, I did not meant to replace your distro/system Python, but just build your own in your homedir. If you put https://gist.github.com/oberstet/9781098 into a script, you can test. This isn't Autobahn related, but Twisted being too old.

Comment: Thanks, oberstet!  I got the examples to work after upgrading the Twisted packages using Ubuntu PPA to version 12.1.0.

Comment: Alright, the "hardcore" solution (upgrade the whole system);) Great to hear it works for you now!